# vim sed match more than one newline and replace it with one newline

Tags: regex, vim, sed

I'm having some trouble with vim, gg=G doesn't remove extra newlines, I'm trying with

```
:%s/\(\n\)\n\+/\1/g
```

but it's not working in the whole file.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question.  I didn't realize that `\n` was so hard to match in `vim`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work in `vim`...

`:g/^\s*$/d`

Answer (score 0):

```
" Put the function bellow in your vimrc
" remove extra newlines keeping the cursor position and search registers
fun! DelBlank()
   let _s=@/
   let l = line(".")
   let c = col(".")
   :g/^\n\{2,}/d
   let @/=_s
   call cursor(l, c)
endfun
" the function can be called with "leader" d see :h <leader>
map <special> <leader>d :keepjumps call DelBlank()<cr>
```